# My python interpreter behaving strange

Tags: python

I am seeing some random behavior while running the below piece of code in **python command line** interpreter. Basically I opened 2 sessions of the same command line interpreter for python in windows,

### Interpreter 1:

```
head,*tail = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
head + sum(tail)
output : 21
```

### Interpreter 2:

```
head,*tail = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
head + sum(tail)
output : Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
         TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Note: I am using pythons inbuilt `sum()` function here.

Can you please help me understand why is this weird behavior and which one is correct behavior.

Comment: What interpreters are you using? What version of python?

Comment: And, are you sure that the version is the same in both sessions? Can you post the output from `print(sys.version)` in both sessions?

Comment: Its the standard python interpreter that comes default with python installation. I am using python 3.6.3 version

Comment: sys.version is '3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]' for both sessions,

Comment: Is there any code before what you've shown us here? The most obvious case would be that you've overwritten `sum` somewhere. You can override many inbuilt functions in python.

Comment: No I have opened 2 fresh sessions.

Comment: Show a little more: try `repr()` for each of `head`, `tail`, and `sum`, and `id(sum)`. You've shown that there is a difference, the question is where and why.

Comment: If you open another bunch of sessions and try it from scratch, how many times out of 10 do you get output 2? The expected output is definitely output 1.

Comment: @YannVernier : The difference is in the output of the 2 sessions shown above.

Comment: @SCB : I have again verified.In one sessions I always get output 1,in other session I always get output 2

Comment: What does `repr(sum)` show for each session?

Comment: Terrible car analogy time: You call up an auto mechanic, and tell him your car goes the wrong way. He asks you what gear it's in, and you say you already told him it goes the wrong way.

Comment: the real question is, why is `tail` None. I would look at that rather than `sum`

Comment: its likely you are actually using different interpreter environments. that syntax is a recent addition so older versions will behave differently

Comment: @avigil `tail` is not None - one of the elements inside it is. If the interpreter didn't support the syntax, then a SyntaxError would have been thrown on the first line.

Comment: what do you get when you print head , tail  & sum(tail) in session 2

Comment: @SmartManoj : head = 1 ,tail =[2,3,4,5,6] and sum(tail) = 20 error comes when I run head + sum(tail)

Comment: Which still really sounds like you've redefined `sum` to be a function that *prints* the result instead of *returning* it. If you'd show us `repr(sum)` and `repr(sum(tail))` that would be clearer.